Truncating text on an unknown expanded div
Right now, I have an Unsplash image of unknown width. You'll see regardless of the image width, the div will expand.
Because it is unknown width, I can't figure out how to truncate my text without adding the width:100px to the code.
I'd like to be able to remove that piece of code and have it truncate the text.
How can I do this with unknown widths?


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex gap-2 overflow-x-scroll flex-shrink-0 px-6 md:px-8">
  <!-- This will eventually be a for-each loop over items in an array, the image size is unknown -->
  <div class="flex-shrink-0 object-fit overflow-hidden">
    <img class="h-24 object-fit rounded-lg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353977828-2a4eab540b9a?q=80&w=1974&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="" />
    <div
      style="font-size:10px;width:100px;"
      class="flex items-center gap-1 mt-1 text-neutral-900 border overflow-hidden max-w-auto"
    >
      <img
        class="w-2.5 h-2.5 rounded-full"
        alt=""
        src="https://static-00.iconduck.com/assets.00/profile-circle-icon-2048x2048-cqe5466q.png"
      />
      <div class="truncate">Long examples name that should ellipsis</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end loop -->
</div>




@elveti wow that's a wild hack. It works! I wonder why. Thank you so much.

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Using the same techniques as this Q&A and adding
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;



.parent {
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 70vh;
}

.description {
  width: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1004/900/600">
  <div class="description">
    Fusce consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl. Duis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum.
  </div>
</div>



